# javascript search string for phrase

Tags: javascript

I have a script that I am working on that I am a little lost on.

I grab a user input (using jQuery) and then loop through an array and see if a phrase from the array exists in the user input. If it is found I am popping up an alert box telling them its found. But for some reason its not working.

Code:

```
submit = false;

            for(i in keyphrases_array) {
                if(english_text.indexOf(keyphrases_array[i]) != -1) {
                    if(trans_text.indexOf(keyphrases_array[i]) != -1) {
                        submit = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    submit = true;
                }
            }
```

`keyphrases_array` is a global array that is set in another function.

Example:

If in my array I have the phrase "Hello World" and my script finds Hello World in the `english_text` variable it then checks the user submitted text (`trans_text`). If the phrase is not found in `trans_text` then the script should return false.

Comment: You might need to show more code.

Comment: What behavior are you getting? Also: your indexOf check is seeing if the text is in the string and if it is `submit = false`. Based on your question, though, it seems like you should be returning `true` there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use `for/in` to iterate over an array. Use a plain `for` loop.

The problem is likely that the value of `submit` is being overwritten by the next iteration in the loop. If that's the end of the function, you should return immediately.

```
submit = false;

for(var i = 0; i < keyphrases_array.length; i++) {
    if(english_text.indexOf(keyphrases_array[i]) != -1) {
          if(trans_text.indexOf(keyphrases_array[i]) != -1) {
                  // return immediately
                return false;
          }
     } else {
           submit = true;
     }
}
return submit;
```

or if there needs to be more processing, you can just break the loop:

```
submit = false;

for(var i = 0; i < keyphrases_array.length; i++) {
    if(english_text.indexOf(keyphrases_array[i]) != -1) {
          if(trans_text.indexOf(keyphrases_array[i]) != -1) {
               submit = false;
               break;
          }
     } else {
           submit = true;
     }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, it seems that you want to `return false` if the text is *not* found in `trans_text`. This would meant that the test should use `==` instead of `!=`.

```
      if(trans_text.indexOf(keyphrases_array[i]) == -1) {
              // return immediately
            return false;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous code would return true if the text was only in the english version, you need to only pass true if it's in both. - Did I understand correctly?

```
 submit = false;

                for(i in keyphrases_array) {
                    if(english_text.indexOf(keyphrases_array[i]) != -1 && trans_text.indexOf(keyphrases_array[i]) != -1) {
                            submit = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        submit = false;
                    }
                }
```

EDIT: Switched true / false around to match the question

Comment: the script first searches the english and if it finds the phrase it then needs to search the translated text. If the translated text does not contain the phrase then it needs to return false. I have certain keyphrases that cannot be translated. Thus this script has given birth lol... Thanks for the help thus far!